# How can I get the background color using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I have an `iframe` and I would like to set up the color white if the background is black and vice-versa. I tried to get the background color with:

```
$("#id").css('background')
```

and

```
$("#id").css('background-color')
```

and

```
$("#id").css('backgroundColor')
```

but they all return transparent.

Please help me.

Comment: could it be that `#id`'s background _is_ transparent?

Comment: if it's transparent then how do I get the parent background?

Comment: I test  $("#id").css("background-color")) and return color in format rgb(255, 0, 0).

Comment: I didn't set background-color anywhere i just set background: #000000 (or other color). is it because of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be looking at the background of the iframe's body, not the background of the `<iframe>` element itself.

```
var bgcolor = $(document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.body).css('background-color');
```

(won't work if iframe content is from a domain different from yours)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined

Comment: Apparently not one of my best days. Fixed.

Comment: yeah ... the body has transparent too. But still my background is black

Comment: The background color might be from some other element within the iframe. It won't be trivial to determine heuristically which element gives the background color of the content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11931/discussion-between-paul-moldovan-and-lanzz)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can walk the parents until you get a background-color that is not transparent:

```
var elm = $("#id")[0],
    bg;

do {

    bg = $(elm).css( "backgroundColor" );
    elm = elm.parentNode;
} while( elm && bg.toLowerCase() === "transparent" );


console.log( bg );
```